# Stop running a cucumber test feature

Tags: ruby, testing, cucumber

Is it possible to cancel a cucumber test while it is running? I have tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>esc</kbd>, but to no avail. The only way I can stop cucumber once I have started running tests is to wait for the tests to finish or to manually kill the process using the operating system. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> twice. It should stop immediately.

Comment: Thanks - this works great. It invokes the --wip switch and stops the tests. You gotta be fast with your fingers though. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>. It stops the test but messes a few things up because I think it thinks the process is still going. If you try `rake db:test:prepare` after you've stopped the test, that usually works. It takes a minute or so, but it's faster than waiting for a long test with lots of JavaScript.

Comment: CTRL+Z doesn't terminate a process, but suspends it. I would recommend `CTRL+Z` and then `kill -9 %1`.

Answer (score 1):

`CTRL+Z` on mac

Pressing twice `CTRL+C` on windows

will interrupt the cucumber tests